# Eclipse not detecting new files in a maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project that is on a mercurial repository.

I can pull and import it into eclipse fine but when someone else adds a new file eclipse does not detect this.
Currently i am deleting the project (just from eclipse not from disk) and re-importing it to be able to see the new files.

I have my eclipse workbench folder next to the root folder for my project.

Any ideas on how to get eclipse to detect the new files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the project in the project explorer, then press `F5` or right click->refresh.